# RegEx for valid international mobile phone number

Tags: regex, validation, phone-number, clickatell

I use Clickatell to send SMSes to clients' mobile phones.

Is there a standardised regular expression for all valid mobile phone numbers, e.g. +27 123 4567? I'd roll my own, but I'm worried about missing an obscure, valid phone number format.

Comment: Why not try sending an SMS to the number your customer gives you? Have the SMS contain a unique code that the customer needs to enter in order to proceed.

Comment: Whoa!! You said this back in 2011. And today we have this widely used concept of OTP.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

After stripping all characters except '+' and digits from your input, this should do it:

```
^\+[1-9]{1}[0-9]{3,14}$
```

If you want to be more exact with the country codes see this question on [List of phone number country codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530377/list-of-phone-number-country-codes)

However, I would try to be not too strict with my validation. Users get very frustrated if they are told their valid numbers are not acceptable.

Comment: I think even that's too strict; the size of the international prefix and local number can both vary.

Comment: @snoopy: last time I checked it looked like the digits in [international prefix] + [local number] is constant - i.e. smaller countries with shorter local numbers have a longer country prefix.

Comment: I took my information from http://www.workingsoftware.com.au/page/International_Mobile_Number_Validation_PT_II which maintains a list of international mobile number formats. Have copied the list to http://pastebin.com/ziYj1uy4

Comment: @snoopy: good link! Yes, in that case ^\+[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7,11}$ is probably the strictest one can go.

Comment: It didn't validate 12 digit UK number (for ex +447735234817)

Comment: Check your syntax @Manish and try again: http://refiddle.com/refiddles/5415ed5875622d4df7370a00

Comment: According to [E.164](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164) international number can be 15 digits long and has no minimum length, other than the country code - at least one digit, and the subscriber number - at least one digit (shortest I've seen is three digits). So the above regex should be: `^\+[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1,14}$`

Comment: Excellent reference, Sergei! I'll adapt my answer, but will consider suspicious anyone with an international telephone number shorter than four digits.

Comment: Fair enough. The shortest one I've found so far was from NZ and was 5 digits long: +64010. Since E.164 doesn't define minimum, personally, I would allow for a two digit-long international number just to be future proof.

Comment: Regardless of any specific country code, this `^([0|\+[0-9]{1,5})?([0-9]{10})$` will also work for generic phone numbers, starting from either `+` or any other number

Comment: this not works on whole countries. because prefix length and whole digits length variable. so may regex not complete solution.

Comment: This does not validate phone numbers with '00' prefix. "+420"=="00420"

Comment: @zdarsky.peter unless your app will be for users from only one country, it is  best practice to reject numbers that start with any county's international dialling prefix instead of a `+`.  From the example given in the question, it is clear that the OP thinks so too.

Comment: I used @"^[1-9+]{1}[0-9]{3,14}" in C#

Answer (score 6):

Even if you write a regular expression that matches exactly the subset "valid phone numbers" out of strings, there is no way to guarantee (by way of a regular expression) that they are valid *mobile* phone numbers. In several countries, mobile phone numbers are indistinguishable from landline phone numbers without at least a number plan lookup, and in some cases, even that won't help. For example, in Sweden, lots of people have "ported" their regular, landline-like phone number to their mobile phone. It's still the same number as they had before, but now it goes to a mobile phone instead of a landline.

Since valid phone numbers consist only of digits, I doubt that rolling your own would risk missing some obscure case of *phone number* at least. If you want to have better certainty, write a generator that takes a list of all valid country codes, and requires one of them at the beginning of the phone number to be matched by the generated regular expression.

Comment: I understand that not all mobile numbers exist, I just need to validate the format due to data entry errors (e.g. filling in the wrong field).

Comment: @FreshCode, that's not what I meant. What I am saying is that you can have phone numbers where there is absolutely no way to tell from the sequence of digits whether it's a landline or mobile phone. Since your question was for a regex to check whether a given string is a valid *mobile phone* number, this is relevant.

Comment: good point. I should probably clarify that by validity I mean, "a potential phone number", e.g. 12345, but not xyz123.

Answer (score 3):

```
^\+[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7,11}$
```

The Regular Expression  `^\+[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7,11}$`  fails for "+290 8000" and similar valid numbers that are shorter than 8 digits.

The longest numbers could be something like 3 digit country code, 3 digit area code, 8 digit subscriber number, making 14 digits.

Answer (score 2):

Posting a note here for users looking into this into the future.  Google's `libphonenumber` is what you most likely would want to use.  There is wrappers for PHP, node.js, Java, etc. to use the data which Google has been collecting and reduces the requirements for maintaining large arrays of regex patterns to apply.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it is about international numbers I would want the code to be like :

```
/^(\+|\d)[0-9]{7,16}$/;
```

As you can have international numbers starting with '00' as well.

Why I prefer 15 digits : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164

Answer (score 0):

// Regex - Check Singapore valid mobile numbers

```
public static boolean isSingaporeMobileNo(String str) {
    Pattern mobNO = Pattern.compile("^(((0|((\\+)?65([- ])?))|((\\((\\+)?65\\)([- ])?)))?[8-9]\\d{7})?$");
    Matcher matcher = mobNO.matcher(str);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```