# Validate phone number ios

Tags: iphone, ios, regex, ipad

I need to validate an international phone number.

I know its difficult to validate an international phone number, so I'm going to keep it simple:

`+` or 00 then 6-14 numbers

My current code using a regex isn't working for some reason which I can't work out. It just says that it cannot open the regex and crashes.

Here is my current code:

```
NSString *phoneRegex = @"^[\+(00)][0-9]{6,14}$";
NSPredicate *phoneTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", phoneRegex];

BOOL phoneValidates = [phoneTest evaluateWithObject:phoneNumber];
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41982/716216 http://stackoverflow.com/a/5933940/716216

Comment: Thanks - this is why I'm keeping it simple. The API call will validate it completely, I just want to restrict the number of calls if possible.

Comment: Related, better answer IMO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063278

Comment: Best way is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39676845/1971013).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
NSString *phoneRegex = @"^((\\+)|(00))[0-9]{6,14}$";
```

This way is bit better. Your code will work as well if you escape the "\".

Comment: The \ was escaping the `+`... do I still need to escape the `+`?

Comment: you need to escape the slash first to "enter" within the string. the \\ will result in \ for regexp.

Comment: But this only works for countries following the ITU recommendation. Japan, the united status and a few other countries use a different prefix. Am I correct in thinking that your code would not cater for these countries? If so, perhaps modify your code to accept a variety of prefixes as opposed to just 00?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_international_call_prefixes

Comment: Why are the parentheses needed here, wouldn't it be equally good with `@"^(\\+|00)[0-9]{6,14}$";`?

Answer (score 16):

**Copy & Paste** method to validate phone numbers:

```
- (BOOL)validatePhone:(NSString *)phoneNumber
{
    NSString *phoneRegex = @"^((\\+)|(00))[0-9]{6,14}$";
    NSPredicate *phoneTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", phoneRegex];

    return [phoneTest evaluateWithObject:phoneNumber];
}
```

or **Open source** Library for validating Phone Numbers

https://github.com/iziz/libPhoneNumber-iOS

Comment: Would it be possible to use a phone validation library such as this one : [link](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) ? Very complete and offers a lot of services.

Answer (score 2):

well it depends on how strict you want to be it doesn't seem like this regex is especially strict. this regex says:

start at beginning of line
match one + (or maybe 1 or 0) which seems ambiguous (but may not be depending on implementation) because the capture parentheses:() breaks up the relationship of the + and the ?
possibly misplaced :
match any digit 0-9 1 or 0 times 6-14 times
then one digit 0-9
then end of line.
also you note that any backslash will have to be doubled... @"\b" for a word boundary. you may want to try something like...

```
@"\\b[\\d]{3}\\-[\\d]{3}\\-[\\d]{4}\\b"
would I think match your example, but it wouldn't match
(555) 555 - 5555 or
555.555.5555 or
+44 1865  55555
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. Have you copied an answer from another

Comment: @vikramjain if phone number have alphabets then how can we parse it? Like Apple Inc phone number is 1800MYAPPLE. Any regex for it?

Answer (score 2):

The only good way to validate phone numbers is to use [Google's amazing LibPhoneNumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber). There's an iOS port, or you can run the JavaScript implementation in a hidden `UIWebView`.

(I've done the latter years ago when their was no iOS port yet. Works like a charm and is very fast even on old iPhones.)

Comment: I think that's a good suggestion, but the ask was specifically about how to get a piece of code to work. I've worked on specific bits of validation where we had narrow requirements, and a library was overkill.

Comment: @benc A 'piece of code' will always fail because of the complexity of telephone numbering. There's no other way than to use a library. Having a quick look at the main resource file LibPhoneNumber should convince you immediately.

Comment: I've tested more than a couple phone number handlers, I don't need a lot of convincing. But sometimes, the person asking isn't going to be able to use that, even if its the best solution.

Comment: @benc It's not a matter of good and better, but of incorrect and correct. Of course someone asking is free to use incorrect phone number formatting and annoy users.

Answer (score 2):

`NSString *phoneRegex = @"^((\\+)|(00))[0-9]{6,14}|[0-9]{6,14}$";`

This is tested RegularExpression
This will accept with country code OR without country code

Comment: Beware. This crashes in iOS 15.

Answer (score 1):

txtlpmobile.text is the string(Mobile no ur gonna enter)

```
 int length = [self getLength:txtLpMobile.text];
            if(length == 10) {
                if(range.length == 0)
                    return NO;
            }
            if(length == 3){
                NSString *num = [self formatNumber:txtLpMobile.text];
                txtLpMobile.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) ",num];

                if(range.length > 0) {
                    txtLpMobile.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[num substringToIndex:3]];

                }
            } else if(length == 6) {
                NSString *num = [self formatNumber:txtLpMobile.text];
                txtLpMobile.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) %@-",[num  substringToIndex:3],[num substringFromIndex:3]];
                if(range.length > 0) {
                    txtLpMobile.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) %@",[num substringToIndex:3],[num substringFromIndex:3]];
                }
            }

            NSUInteger newLength;
            newLength = [txtLpMobile.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
            NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:NUMBERS_ONLY] invertedSet];
            NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
            return (([string isEqualToString:filtered])&&(newLength <= CHARACTER_LIMIT));
```

for formatting number

```
-(NSString*)formatNumber:(NSString*)mobileNumber
{
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@""];

    int length = [mobileNumber length];
    if(length > 10)
    {
        mobileNumber = [mobileNumber substringFromIndex: length-10];
    }
    return mobileNumber;
}
```

for getting length

```
-(int)getLength:(NSString*)mobileNumber
{
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@""];

    int length = [mobileNumber length];

    return length;
}
```

Comment: Does not support international phone numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to validate phone number and password limit , just follow the below process.

```
if ((self.mobileTxtFld.text.length < 10 )) {
    [_mobileTxtFld becomeFirstResponder];
}
else if ((self.passwordTxtFld.text.length < kPasswordCharacterMinLimit) || (self.passwordTxtFld.text.length > kPasswordCharacterMaxLimit)) {
    // show alert
}
```

after that you can implement textfiled delegate method "shouldChangeCharactersInRange" in that just write this code

```
if (textField == _mobileTxtFld) {
    if([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:ALLOWED_NUMBERS].location == NSNotFound){
        NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
        if(newLength > kMobileNumberLimit - 1){
            if(textField.text.length != kMobileNumberLimit){
                textField.text  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",textField.text,string];
            }
            [textField resignFirstResponder];
            return NO;
        }
        else{
            return YES;
        }
    }
    else{
        return NO;
    }
}

return YES;
```

here ALLOWED_NUMBERS and kMobileNumberLimit are

```
#define kMobileNumberLimit 10
#define ALLOWED_NUMBERS [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]
#define minLimit 6
#define maxLimit 17
```

Answer (score 0):

In swift 4 -

```
func ValidateMobileNumber(txtFeid : UITextField, strChk : String, range: NSRange) -> Bool {

    if txtFeid.text!.count >= 10 {
        return false
    } 

    let formatePre = "^((\\+)|(00))[0-9]{6,14}$"
    let resultPredicate : NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@",formatePre)
    return resultPredicate.evaluate(with: strChk)
}
```

Answer (score -4):

```
-(int)findLength:(NSString*)phoneNumber
{
    phoneNumber = [phoneNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
    phoneNumber = [phoneNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
    phoneNumber = [phoneNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    phoneNumber = [phoneNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
    phoneNumber = [phoneNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@""];

int length = [phoneNumber length];

return length;
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! An answer was already provided and accepted (4 years ago) for this question! Does your answer bring something new ? If so, you should explain why.