# How to check user entered phone number is valid or not in Objective c?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

In my project i have validate a phone number with country code like if user enter number is 44557788991 and select country US.same like for other country how can i check the phone number is valid or not.

[image]

on button click i have to check number is valid or not.

Comment: This may help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176083/validate-phone-number-ios

Comment: Did you mean you want to check the number exists or not ?

Comment: i want to check number by country code like user select US then number according to number format. @Maulik

Comment: The question itself is silly.

Answer (score 7):

I think you want to check the number country wise. for this you have to use following demo

https://github.com/rmaddy/RMPhoneFormat

for UK

```
    RMPhoneFormat *fmt = [[RMPhoneFormat alloc] initWithDefaultCountry:@"uk"];
    NSString *numberString = // the phone number to format
    NSString *formattedNumber = [fmt format:numberString];
```

for Australia

```
RMPhoneFormat *fmt = [RMPhoneFormat instance];
NSString *callingCode = [fmt callingCodeForCountryCode:@"AU"]; // Australia - returns 61
NSString *defaultCallingCode = [fmt defaultCallingCode]; // based on current Region Format (locale)
```

and so on...

Comment: this is good but i want to check something like in first textField user enter phone number and then select country code after this i click on button and want to get out put like...
Number:1234567890
Code:IN
 isValidPhoneNumber ? [YES]
164          : +911234567890
INTERNATIONAL : +91 1234 567 890
NATIONAL      : 01234 567 890
FC3966       : tel:+91-1234-567-890
extractCountryCode [82]
extractCountryCode [82] [3213123123].
i get this out using https://github.com/me2day/libPhoneNumber-iOS.

but when i call send time my app is crash @SAMIR RATHOD

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSDataDetector to check if the phone number is valid:

```
- (BOOL)isValidPhoneNumber:(NSString*)phoneNumber {
    NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber error:nil];
    NSTextCheckingResult *result = [detector firstMatchInString:phoneNumber options:NSMatchingReportCompletion range:NSMakeRange(0, [phoneNumber length])];
    if ([result resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```