# Deducing cellular network iPhone

Tags: objective-c, cellular-network

Is it possible to know cellular network/Operator for any mobile number provided (Not for the current sim used in mobile) in objective c?

Comment: Mobile number is not tied to operator anymore, so no, at least not from the number itself.

Comment: you can identify the network type. But not sure the operator http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400340/determining-3g-vs-edge/13127014#13127014

Comment: @Jarc, Thanks for your quick reply. Is there any solution to validate if the entered mobile number is valid or not?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176083/validate-phone-number-ios?answertab=active#tab-top check out here

Comment: @Puvanarajan This is not what I am looking for. Thanks for your support!

Comment: @ShashiTiwari: if you are thinking of 'if it looks valid' then there are a couple of regex-es that can do this (kind of, none of them are 100%). If you are thinking of 'if certain number is active' then no.

Comment: You need to use an HLR lookup service. Most have APIs available, although I'm not sure about Obj C.