# Titanium- phone number recognition and on click call

Tags: regex, titanium, phone-number

In my titanium app i have a simple contact form which is just a label with some text in it.

In that text there are phone numbers and my question is, is it possible for my app to recognise that as a phone number and when the user clicks on it to ask him if he wants to make a call to that number? ( i can only test for android since i am on a PC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For making a call Follow this link .

[Call using titanium](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/27711/calling-a-phone-number)

And for auto detection of a phone number .. Its better if you go for a regular expression to check . once you find a match then call using the link I gave else don't.

Here's some of the reg ex link for Phone numbers

[reg Ex 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113908/what-regular-expression-will-match-valid-international-phone-numbers)

[reg Ex 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066329/regex-for-valid-international-mobile-phone-number)