# Information about a phone number

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

Is there any lib for node.js that receives a phone number (in any format), converts it to a default format, and tells me info about the number (e.g.: country, city, etc)?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not aware of one and I also searched the [npm registry](http://search.npmjs.org/).

Google has [libphonenumber](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/) for dealing with phone numbers and has a javascript API.

From their site:

> Google's common Java, C++ and Javascript library for parsing,
>   formatting, storing and validating international phone numbers. The
>   Java version is optimized for running on smartphones.

There's also an SO post on getting phone country codes:  [List of phone number country codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530377/list-of-phone-number-country-codes)

Comment: The `PhoneNumberOfflineGeocoder` in libphonenumber looks perfect.

Answer (score 2):

While not a Node.js library, I think [Number Laundry](http://numberlaundry.whatcheer.com/) would fit your requirements (although it seems they only return the country, not the city):

> Number Laundry is a tiny API that accepts phone numbers and returns helpful information as json:

Since you tagged the question with `twilio`, you might like that it returns Twilio rate data in addition to the other information:

```
{
  // The number you passed us
  "source": "+45 66 22 22 12",
  "error": false,
  // A nice clean format for your database (only: 0-9 and +)
  "clean": "+4566222212",
  // Twilio rate data
  "twilio": {
    "rate": "0.033",
    "prefix": "45"
  },
  // Country information (when available)
  "country": {
    "name": "Denmark",
    "code": "DK",
    "flag": "http:\/\/numberlaundry-icons.s3.amazonaws.com\/dk.png"
  }
}
```

They have the [source on github](https://github.com/WhatCheer/Number-Laundry), so you could probably port it to node if you wanted. If you're looking for more than just country info, checkout [NumberGuru](http://www.numberguru.com/developer) (although they're in limited alpha).

Answer (score 0):

I build a library recently that run libphonenumber over NodeJs: https://github.com/Socialcam/node-libphonenumber

It might just solve your problem and you can deploy it in a snap over Heroku!

Answer (score 0):

Consider also a simplified pure javascript port (no external dependencies) of Google's `libphonenumber`:
https://github.com/halt-hammerzeit/libphonenumber-js