# How to show country flags according to phone numbers in android?

Tags: android

I want to display country flags with respect to phone-numbers in my contact lists like rebtel(Screen shot shown below).

> [image]

Comment: Simple solution : image name should be of country name :) now compare text with image name and display that map.

Comment: Why is it down voted with out reason. Let me know the reason before down voting

Comment: @Kedarnath. Some one did it with out any explanation.

Comment: we live in democracy. Different people, different thinking, concentrate on the answer, not on the downvotes :)

Comment: Yes, I am not worrying about down voting. But he should explain reason. Okay Thank you

Comment: @Kedarnath's solution is much easy to implement. I'd do the same way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the phone number and get the international prefix, then you can use Wikipedia: [List_of_country_calling_codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes#Alphabetical_listing_by_country_or_region) to get the country. You can implement a Map with key being the international prefix and key the country name.

Comment: I am getting international prefix with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16809508/extract-code-country-from-phone-number-libphonenumber/16835306#16835306

Answer (score 1):

Here I am giving you the logic part,

You can get the ISD code and flag image from this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes#Alphabetical_listing_by_country_or_region

You need to make two Array variables,

```
 String [] countryCode  = new String { "+91","+92", ... };
 int [] country = new int { R.drawable.91.png, R.drawable.92.png,.... };

 // Considering here 91.png is india's map
```

Now get the phone number from contact list , suppose you have +91987654321. So remove first + sign and compare 91 to all the resources images. When match found, put that image with the contact.

Comment: Thank you kedarnath for your answer, but jabaldonedo is very useful to me

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this library](https://github.com/dlukashev/android-phone-number-with-flags) for your Requirement.

Go to detail you can show country flag and country code with use of this.