# How to get the country code from local phone number input without knowing what country it is from

Tags: android

I have used PhoneNumberUtil as a tool for converting a phone number to international. However, if a user input is a local phone number which the app doesn't know what country the local phone number is from. How can you determine its country code.

My Code.

```
String phoneNumberParse = phoneNumberTextInput.getText().toString();
        PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
        try {
            Phonenumber.PhoneNumber convertedPhoneNumber = phoneUtil.parse(phoneNumberParse, null);

        newPhoneNumber = phoneUtil.format(convertedPhoneNumber, PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberFormat.E164);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), newPhoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (NumberParseException e) {
            System.out.print("Phone Util"+e);
        }
```

Comment: See this link : https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber

Comment: That's exactly what I use.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16809508/extract-code-country-from-phone-number-libphonenumber

Comment: @chipopo You can only do that if your number starts with "+" which means it should contain country code. What I wanted to know is how to determine the country code if your input is a local like "0699xxx"

Comment: try to format your number using the PhoneNumberFormat.E164 instead of PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL. this will format your 0699xxx into a number with its country code: "+xxx xxx.."

Comment: Still doesn't do that. I edited the post for the update.

Comment: you have got any solution to this?  I also need to check given phone number is national or international

Comment: @Bryan You got any solution?? i also stuck in my app.

Answer (score 0):

You work with "chunks". The international phone numbers come in 4-6 chunks; with the first chunk being the country code: e.g.

- +92 333 123 4567: Pakistan (92)
- +1 212 456 7890: U.S. (1)
- +33 7 56 78 90 12: France (33)

Tablulate the leading nodes (and their Country names, currency code (while your at it); and add country "node count" for validation.

I'm assuming that's all you have; unless you have address information; which you should / could validate against an international "address" service (a few cents here and there).

Answer (score 0):

The "PhoneNumberUtil" library should be capable of parsing the country code from a phone number, but it requires the number to be in international format, which starts with a '+' followed by the country code.

Here's how you can tweak your code to parse the country code:

```
String phoneNumberParse = phoneNumberTextInput.getText().toString();
PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
try {
    // The phone number must begin with '+'
    Phonenumber.PhoneNumber numberProto = phoneUtil.parse(phoneNumberParse, "");
    int countryCode = numberProto.getCountryCode();
    System.out.println("Country Code: " + countryCode);
} catch (NumberParseException e) {
    System.err.println("NumberParseException was thrown: " + e.toString());
}
```

In this code, I'm calling the `parse` method with an empty string as the second argument. This instructs the method to expect a number in international format.

This approach requires the phone number to start with a '+'. If the number doesn't start with a '+', the library won't be able to determine the country code.

Or if you want you can use third party library like already mentioned "libphonenumber". You could also use an API that determines the country of origin based on the phone number like "GeoLite2".