# How to get country code and name using mobile number

Tags: java, android

I'm new for android, In my app i have three edittext and one button. If user enter their mobile number and press buttons means automatically country code and country name filled in other edittext.

I used below code

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String countryCodeValue = tm.getNetworkCountryIso();
Log.d("CountryCOde",countryCodeValue);
```

But, It not working in without sim(Tablet). So, i want to get country code and name with help of mobile number. Want to work without sim also.

Comment: How would you like to get information about cellular network without the connection to the network?
My advice would be to find another way to get user location, for example from user location or language set in telephone.

Comment: Then how tablet user using app.. I want to allow particular country

Comment: Then choose the way to get current user location. There are API's that show the country, when passing IP address. And block the user if he is in disallowed country.

Comment: If i Use this: getActivity().getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getCountry(); It return US

Comment: Because you have `en-US` locale set in the phone. Try an approach with user location.

Comment: Check this out. This might help you. [Click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16809508/extract-code-country-from-phone-number-libphonenumber)

Comment: How to get country name from ip address