# Extract country code from phone number in flutter

Tags: flutter, libphonenumber

I have phone number as String like "+91 96001 64500", *(Getting the data from google places API)*  I want to extract the phone number(without country code) as well as country code, without knowing the country (Country can be any country).
How can I do this in flutter.

> Note: There is already another exact same question asked [Extract code country from phone number [libphonenumber]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16809508/extract-code-country-from-phone-number-libphonenumber) but it's for android, I want it for flutter.

Comment: If you have an iOS solution as well, you could use platform specific ones in their respective platform code in Flutter. Why do you wish to extract the country code? I ask to understand better the situation. Maybe it would be better to have the country code entered in a separate field, or from a country the user selects.

Comment: One difficulty is that country codes vary in length, can be +1, +45, +212 and so on.

Comment: @Doh09 I'm working on a project and I get data from Google place API, I need to parse the data and show the country code as well as phone number separately. I'm not getting input from user, it's from Google places API itself, so can't take have the country code entered in a separate field as you said.

Comment: Does the Google API not provide a country name, code like "US" or other data such as coordinates that might indicate location?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details In this example there is "AU" for Australia for example.

Comment: @Doh09 Yes I can get the country code like 'US', 'IN' or 'AU'

Comment: Then just use a key-value variable type. For example a hashmap. Set the key to be the country letters and the value to be the phone code. For example
"US" as key would lead to "+1" as value. https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-collection/HashMap-class.html

Comment: @UttamLaila - Have you found any optimal solution ?

Comment: @Vijay No, I think there is no direct solution to this problem, we can follow Doh09 and Владимир-Прихоженко 's answers.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/phone_number#-example-tab - This package helps.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the function to split dial code and phone number

```
 seperatePhoneAndDialCode() {
    Map<String, String> foundedCountry = {};
    for (var country in Countries.allCountries) {
      String dialCode = country["dial_code"].toString();
      if (phoneWithDialCode.value.contains(dialCode)) {
        foundedCountry = country;
      }
    }

    if (foundedCountry.isNotEmpty) {
      var dialCode = phoneWithDialCode.value.substring(
        0,
        foundedCountry["dial_code"]!.length,
      );
      var newPhoneNumber = phoneWithDialCode.value.substring(
        foundedCountry["dial_code"]!.length,
      );
      print({dialCode, newPhoneNumber});
    }
  }
```

Don't forget to copy the below code and paste it into a new dart file.

```
class Countries {
  static List<Map<String, String>> allCountries = [
    {"name": "Afghanistan", "dial_code": "+93", "code": "AF"},
    {"name": "Aland Islands", "dial_code": "+358", "code": "AX"},
    {"name": "Albania", "dial_code": "+355", "code": "AL"},
    {"name": "Algeria", "dial_code": "+213", "code": "DZ"},
    {"name": "AmericanSamoa", "dial_code": "+1684", "code": "AS"},
    {"name": "Andorra", "dial_code": "+376", "code": "AD"},
    {"name": "Angola", "dial_code": "+244", "code": "AO"},
    {"name": "Anguilla", "dial_code": "+1264", "code": "AI"},
    {"name": "Antarctica", "dial_code": "+672", "code": "AQ"},
    {"name": "Antigua and Barbuda", "dial_code": "+1268", "code": "AG"},
    {"name": "Argentina", "dial_code": "+54", "code": "AR"},
    {"name": "Armenia", "dial_code": "+374", "code": "AM"},
    {"name": "Aruba", "dial_code": "+297", "code": "AW"},
    {"name": "Australia", "dial_code": "+61", "code": "AU"},
    {"name": "Austria", "dial_code": "+43", "code": "AT"},
    {"name": "Azerbaijan", "dial_code": "+994", "code": "AZ"},
    {"name": "Bahamas", "dial_code": "+1242", "code": "BS"},
    {"name": "Bahrain", "dial_code": "+973", "code": "BH"},
    {"name": "Bangladesh", "dial_code": "+880", "code": "BD"},
    {"name": "Barbados", "dial_code": "+1246", "code": "BB"},
    {"name": "Belarus", "dial_code": "+375", "code": "BY"},
    {"name": "Belgium", "dial_code": "+32", "code": "BE"},
    {"name": "Belize", "dial_code": "+501", "code": "BZ"},
    {"name": "Benin", "dial_code": "+229", "code": "BJ"},
    {"name": "Bermuda", "dial_code": "+1441", "code": "BM"},
    {"name": "Bhutan", "dial_code": "+975", "code": "BT"},
    {
      "name": "Bolivia, Plurinational State of",
      "dial_code": "+591",
      "code": "BO"
    },
    {"name": "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "dial_code": "+387", "code": "BA"},
    {"name": "Botswana", "dial_code": "+267", "code": "BW"},
    {"name": "Brazil", "dial_code": "+55", "code": "BR"},
    {
      "name": "British Indian Ocean Territory",
      "dial_code": "+246",
      "code": "IO"
    },
    {"name": "Brunei Darussalam", "dial_code": "+673", "code": "BN"},
    {"name": "Bulgaria", "dial_code": "+359", "code": "BG"},
    {"name": "Burkina Faso", "dial_code": "+226", "code": "BF"},
    {"name": "Burundi", "dial_code": "+257", "code": "BI"},
    {"name": "Cambodia", "dial_code": "+855", "code": "KH"},
    {"name": "Cameroon", "dial_code": "+237", "code": "CM"},
    {"name": "Canada", "dial_code": "+1", "code": "CA"},
    {"name": "Cape Verde", "dial_code": "+238", "code": "CV"},
    {"name": "Cayman Islands", "dial_code": "+ 345", "code": "KY"},
    {"name": "Central African Republic", "dial_code": "+236", "code": "CF"},
    {"name": "Chad", "dial_code": "+235", "code": "TD"},
    {"name": "Chile", "dial_code": "+56", "code": "CL"},
    {"name": "China", "dial_code": "+86", "code": "CN"},
    {"name": "Christmas Island", "dial_code": "+61", "code": "CX"},
    {"name": "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", "dial_code": "+61", "code": "CC"},
    {"name": "Colombia", "dial_code": "+57", "code": "CO"},
    {"name": "Comoros", "dial_code": "+269", "code": "KM"},
    {"name": "Congo", "dial_code": "+242", "code": "CG"},
    {
      "name": "Congo, The Democratic Republic of the Congo",
      "dial_code": "+243",
      "code": "CD"
    },
    {"name": "Cook Islands", "dial_code": "+682", "code": "CK"},
    {"name": "Costa Rica", "dial_code": "+506", "code": "CR"},
    {"name": "Cote d'Ivoire", "dial_code": "+225", "code": "CI"},
    {"name": "Croatia", "dial_code": "+385", "code": "HR"},
    {"name": "Cuba", "dial_code": "+53", "code": "CU"},
    {"name": "Cyprus", "dial_code": "+357", "code": "CY"},
    {"name": "Czech Republic", "dial_code": "+420", "code": "CZ"},
    {"name": "Denmark", "dial_code": "+45", "code": "DK"},
    {"name": "Djibouti", "dial_code": "+253", "code": "DJ"},
    {"name": "Dominica", "dial_code": "+1767", "code": "DM"},
    {"name": "Dominican Republic", "dial_code": "+1849", "code": "DO"},
    {"name": "Ecuador", "dial_code": "+593", "code": "EC"},
    {"name": "Egypt", "dial_code": "+20", "code": "EG"},
    {"name": "El Salvador", "dial_code": "+503", "code": "SV"},
    {"name": "Equatorial Guinea", "dial_code": "+240", "code": "GQ"},
    {"name": "Eritrea", "dial_code": "+291", "code": "ER"},
    {"name": "Estonia", "dial_code": "+372", "code": "EE"},
    {"name": "Ethiopia", "dial_code": "+251", "code": "ET"},
    {"name": "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)", "dial_code": "+500", "code": "FK"},
    {"name": "Faroe Islands", "dial_code": "+298", "code": "FO"},
    {"name": "Fiji", "dial_code": "+679", "code": "FJ"},
    {"name": "Finland", "dial_code": "+358", "code": "FI"},
    {"name": "France", "dial_code": "+33", "code": "FR"},
    {"name": "French Guiana", "dial_code": "+594", "code": "GF"},
    {"name": "French Polynesia", "dial_code": "+689", "code": "PF"},
    {"name": "Gabon", "dial_code": "+241", "code": "GA"},
    {"name": "Gambia", "dial_code": "+220", "code": "GM"},
    {"name": "Georgia", "dial_code": "+995", "code": "GE"},
    {"name": "Germany", "dial_code": "+49", "code": "DE"},
    {"name": "Ghana", "dial_code": "+233", "code": "GH"},
    {"name": "Gibraltar", "dial_code": "+350", "code": "GI"},
    {"name": "Greece", "dial_code": "+30", "code": "GR"},
    {"name": "Greenland", "dial_code": "+299", "code": "GL"},
    {"name": "Grenada", "dial_code": "+1473", "code": "GD"},
    {"name": "Guadeloupe", "dial_code": "+590", "code": "GP"},
    {"name": "Guam", "dial_code": "+1671", "code": "GU"},
    {"name": "Guatemala", "dial_code": "+502", "code": "GT"},
    {"name": "Guernsey", "dial_code": "+44", "code": "GG"},
    {"name": "Guinea", "dial_code": "+224", "code": "GN"},
    {"name": "Guinea-Bissau", "dial_code": "+245", "code": "GW"},
    {"name": "Guyana", "dial_code": "+595", "code": "GY"},
    {"name": "Haiti", "dial_code": "+509", "code": "HT"},
    {
      "name": "Holy See (Vatican City State)",
      "dial_code": "+379",
      "code": "VA"
    },
    {"name": "Honduras", "dial_code": "+504", "code": "HN"},
    {"name": "Hong Kong", "dial_code": "+852", "code": "HK"},
    {"name": "Hungary", "dial_code": "+36", "code": "HU"},
    {"name": "Iceland", "dial_code": "+354", "code": "IS"},
    {"name": "India", "dial_code": "+91", "code": "IN"},
    {"name": "Indonesia", "dial_code": "+62", "code": "ID"},
    {
      "name": "Iran, Islamic Republic of Persian Gulf",
      "dial_code": "+98",
      "code": "IR"
    },
    {"name": "Iraq", "dial_code": "+964", "code": "IQ"},
    {"name": "Ireland", "dial_code": "+353", "code": "IE"},
    {"name": "Isle of Man", "dial_code": "+44", "code": "IM"},
    {"name": "Israel", "dial_code": "+972", "code": "IL"},
    {"name": "Italy", "dial_code": "+39", "code": "IT"},
    {"name": "Jamaica", "dial_code": "+1876", "code": "JM"},
    {"name": "Japan", "dial_code": "+81", "code": "JP"},
    {"name": "Jersey", "dial_code": "+44", "code": "JE"},
    {"name": "Jordan", "dial_code": "+962", "code": "JO"},
    {"name": "Kazakhstan", "dial_code": "+77", "code": "KZ"},
    {"name": "Kenya", "dial_code": "+254", "code": "KE"},
    {"name": "Kiribati", "dial_code": "+686", "code": "KI"},
    {
      "name": "Korea, Democratic People's Republic of Korea",
      "dial_code": "+850",
      "code": "KP"
    },
    {
      "name": "Korea, Republic of South Korea",
      "dial_code": "+82",
      "code": "KR"
    },
    {"name": "Kuwait", "dial_code": "+965", "code": "KW"},
    {"name": "Kyrgyzstan", "dial_code": "+996", "code": "KG"},
    {"name": "Laos", "dial_code": "+856", "code": "LA"},
    {"name": "Latvia", "dial_code": "+371", "code": "LV"},
    {"name": "Lebanon", "dial_code": "+961", "code": "LB"},
    {"name": "Lesotho", "dial_code": "+266", "code": "LS"},
    {"name": "Liberia", "dial_code": "+231", "code": "LR"},
    {"name": "Libyan Arab Jamahiriya", "dial_code": "+218", "code": "LY"},
    {"name": "Liechtenstein", "dial_code": "+423", "code": "LI"},
    {"name": "Lithuania", "dial_code": "+370", "code": "LT"},
    {"name": "Luxembourg", "dial_code": "+352", "code": "LU"},
    {"name": "Macao", "dial_code": "+853", "code": "MO"},
    {"name": "Macedonia", "dial_code": "+389", "code": "MK"},
    {"name": "Madagascar", "dial_code": "+261", "code": "MG"},
    {"name": "Malawi", "dial_code": "+265", "code": "MW"},
    {"name": "Malaysia", "dial_code": "+60", "code": "MY"},
    {"name": "Maldives", "dial_code": "+960", "code": "MV"},
    {"name": "Mali", "dial_code": "+223", "code": "ML"},
    {"name": "Malta", "dial_code": "+356", "code": "MT"},
    {"name": "Marshall Islands", "dial_code": "+692", "code": "MH"},
    {"name": "Martinique", "dial_code": "+596", "code": "MQ"},
    {"name": "Mauritania", "dial_code": "+222", "code": "MR"},
    {"name": "Mauritius", "dial_code": "+230", "code": "MU"},
    {"name": "Mayotte", "dial_code": "+262", "code": "YT"},
    {"name": "Mexico", "dial_code": "+52", "code": "MX"},
    {
      "name": "Micronesia, Federated States of Micronesia",
      "dial_code": "+691",
      "code": "FM"
    },
    {"name": "Moldova", "dial_code": "+373", "code": "MD"},
    {"name": "Monaco", "dial_code": "+377", "code": "MC"},
    {"name": "Mongolia", "dial_code": "+976", "code": "MN"},
    {"name": "Montenegro", "dial_code": "+382", "code": "ME"},
    {"name": "Montserrat", "dial_code": "+1664", "code": "MS"},
    {"name": "Morocco", "dial_code": "+212", "code": "MA"},
    {"name": "Mozambique", "dial_code": "+258", "code": "MZ"},
    {"name": "Myanmar", "dial_code": "+95", "code": "MM"},
    {"name": "Namibia", "dial_code": "+264", "code": "NA"},
    {"name": "Nauru", "dial_code": "+674", "code": "NR"},
    {"name": "Nepal", "dial_code": "+977", "code": "NP"},
    {"name": "Netherlands", "dial_code": "+31", "code": "NL"},
    {"name": "Netherlands Antilles", "dial_code": "+599", "code": "AN"},
    {"name": "New Caledonia", "dial_code": "+687", "code": "NC"},
    {"name": "New Zealand", "dial_code": "+64", "code": "NZ"},
    {"name": "Nicaragua", "dial_code": "+505", "code": "NI"},
    {"name": "Niger", "dial_code": "+227", "code": "NE"},
    {"name": "Nigeria", "dial_code": "+234", "code": "NG"},
    {"name": "Niue", "dial_code": "+683", "code": "NU"},
    {"name": "Norfolk Island", "dial_code": "+672", "code": "NF"},
    {"name": "Northern Mariana Islands", "dial_code": "+1670", "code": "MP"},
    {"name": "Norway", "dial_code": "+47", "code": "NO"},
    {"name": "Oman", "dial_code": "+968", "code": "OM"},
    {"name": "Pakistan", "dial_code": "+92", "code": "PK"},
    {"name": "Palau", "dial_code": "+680", "code": "PW"},
    {
      "name": "Palestinian Territory, Occupied",
      "dial_code": "+970",
      "code": "PS"
    },
    {"name": "Panama", "dial_code": "+507", "code": "PA"},
    {"name": "Papua New Guinea", "dial_code": "+675", "code": "PG"},
    {"name": "Paraguay", "dial_code": "+595", "code": "PY"},
    {"name": "Peru", "dial_code": "+51", "code": "PE"},
    {"name": "Philippines", "dial_code": "+63", "code": "PH"},
    {"name": "Pitcairn", "dial_code": "+872", "code": "PN"},
    {"name": "Poland", "dial_code": "+48", "code": "PL"},
    {"name": "Portugal", "dial_code": "+351", "code": "PT"},
    {"name": "Puerto Rico", "dial_code": "+1939", "code": "PR"},
    {"name": "Qatar", "dial_code": "+974", "code": "QA"},
    {"name": "Romania", "dial_code": "+40", "code": "RO"},
    {"name": "Russia", "dial_code": "+7", "code": "RU"},
    {"name": "Rwanda", "dial_code": "+250", "code": "RW"},
    {"name": "Reunion", "dial_code": "+262", "code": "RE"},
    {"name": "Saint Barthelemy", "dial_code": "+590", "code": "BL"},
    {
      "name": "Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan Da Cunha",
      "dial_code": "+290",
      "code": "SH"
    },
    {"name": "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "dial_code": "+1869", "code": "KN"},
    {"name": "Saint Lucia", "dial_code": "+1758", "code": "LC"},
    {"name": "Saint Martin", "dial_code": "+590", "code": "MF"},
    {"name": "Saint Pierre and Miquelon", "dial_code": "+508", "code": "PM"},
    {
      "name": "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines",
      "dial_code": "+1784",
      "code": "VC"
    },
    {"name": "Samoa", "dial_code": "+685", "code": "WS"},
    {"name": "San Marino", "dial_code": "+378", "code": "SM"},
    {"name": "Sao Tome and Principe", "dial_code": "+239", "code": "ST"},
    {"name": "Saudi Arabia", "dial_code": "+966", "code": "SA"},
    {"name": "Senegal", "dial_code": "+221", "code": "SN"},
    {"name": "Serbia", "dial_code": "+381", "code": "RS"},
    {"name": "Seychelles", "dial_code": "+248", "code": "SC"},
    {"name": "Sierra Leone", "dial_code": "+232", "code": "SL"},
    {"name": "Singapore", "dial_code": "+65", "code": "SG"},
    {"name": "Slovakia", "dial_code": "+421", "code": "SK"},
    {"name": "Slovenia", "dial_code": "+386", "code": "SI"},
    {"name": "Solomon Islands", "dial_code": "+677", "code": "SB"},
    {"name": "Somalia", "dial_code": "+252", "code": "SO"},
    {"name": "South Africa", "dial_code": "+27", "code": "ZA"},
    {"name": "South Sudan", "dial_code": "+211", "code": "SS"},
    {
      "name": "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands",
      "dial_code": "+500",
      "code": "GS"
    },
    {"name": "Spain", "dial_code": "+34", "code": "ES"},
    {"name": "Sri Lanka", "dial_code": "+94", "code": "LK"},
    {"name": "Sudan", "dial_code": "+249", "code": "SD"},
    {"name": "Suriname", "dial_code": "+597", "code": "SR"},
    {"name": "Svalbard and Jan Mayen", "dial_code": "+47", "code": "SJ"},
    {"name": "Swaziland", "dial_code": "+268", "code": "SZ"},
    {"name": "Sweden", "dial_code": "+46", "code": "SE"},
    {"name": "Switzerland", "dial_code": "+41", "code": "CH"},
    {"name": "Syrian Arab Republic", "dial_code": "+963", "code": "SY"},
    {"name": "Taiwan", "dial_code": "+886", "code": "TW"},
    {"name": "Tajikistan", "dial_code": "+992", "code": "TJ"},
    {
      "name": "Tanzania, United Republic of Tanzania",
      "dial_code": "+255",
      "code": "TZ"
    },
    {"name": "Thailand", "dial_code": "+66", "code": "TH"},
    {"name": "Timor-Leste", "dial_code": "+670", "code": "TL"},
    {"name": "Togo", "dial_code": "+228", "code": "TG"},
    {"name": "Tokelau", "dial_code": "+690", "code": "TK"},
    {"name": "Tonga", "dial_code": "+676", "code": "TO"},
    {"name": "Trinidad and Tobago", "dial_code": "+1868", "code": "TT"},
    {"name": "Tunisia", "dial_code": "+216", "code": "TN"},
    {"name": "Turkey", "dial_code": "+90", "code": "TR"},
    {"name": "Turkmenistan", "dial_code": "+993", "code": "TM"},
    {"name": "Turks and Caicos Islands", "dial_code": "+1649", "code": "TC"},
    {"name": "Tuvalu", "dial_code": "+688", "code": "TV"},
    {"name": "Uganda", "dial_code": "+256", "code": "UG"},
    {"name": "Ukraine", "dial_code": "+380", "code": "UA"},
    {"name": "United Arab Emirates", "dial_code": "+971", "code": "AE"},
    {"name": "United Kingdom", "dial_code": "+44", "code": "GB"},
    {"name": "United States", "dial_code": "+1", "code": "US"},
    {"name": "Uruguay", "dial_code": "+598", "code": "UY"},
    {"name": "Uzbekistan", "dial_code": "+998", "code": "UZ"},
    {"name": "Vanuatu", "dial_code": "+678", "code": "VU"},
    {
      "name": "Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of Venezuela",
      "dial_code": "+58",
      "code": "VE"
    },
    {"name": "Vietnam", "dial_code": "+84", "code": "VN"},
    {"name": "Virgin Islands, British", "dial_code": "+1284", "code": "VG"},
    {"name": "Virgin Islands, U.S.", "dial_code": "+1340", "code": "VI"},
    {"name": "Wallis and Futuna", "dial_code": "+681", "code": "WF"},
    {"name": "Yemen", "dial_code": "+967", "code": "YE"},
    {"name": "Zambia", "dial_code": "+260", "code": "ZM"},
    {"name": "Zimbabwe", "dial_code": "+263", "code": "ZW"}
  ];
}
```

It will work... (If God Will)

Answer (score 1):

You can save all country codes into the list (for example from here https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Goles/3196253/raw/9ca4e7e62ea5ad935bb3580dc0a07d9df033b451/CountryCodes.json) and make loop on them.
If first letters of your phone number equals to that symbols - it's your coutry code. The rest is phone number)
The list must be sorted by length by descending.

Comment: This can be done. But is there any proper way of doing it using any packages?

Comment: Just parse the JSON into an object and use that.

Comment: Flutter has this section on JSON: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention having access to the country letters. Then just use a key-value variable type. For example a hashmap. Set the key to be the country letters and the value to be the phone code. For example "US" as key would lead to "+1" as value.

Click this link to read more about hashmaps in dart (the programming language used in Flutter): https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-collection/HashMap-class.html