# Googlecode libphonenumber in Java, how to parse PhoneNumber for string "0044*******" or "044*******" where 44 is country code but with zero as prefix

Tags: java, libphonenumber

I tried parsing a string containing phone number but with zero as prefix before international country code using libphonenumber library, it is giving exception :

```
"INVALID_COUNTRY_CODE. Could not interpret numbers after plus-sign."
```

and how to make it work only for two characters of zero before country code or after country but it should fail if it has more that 2 characters of zero.

Comment: Please [edit] you post to include a [mre] the results in the error you describe.

Comment: May be you are trying to parse the phone number. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16809508/extract-code-country-from-phone-number-libphonenumber?rq=2) may help:

Comment: I believe under E.123 that for `+44`, `+` is the international prefix and `44` is the country code. So `044` is the national number syntax, and uses `0` instead of `+`. In this sense, `+044` is nonsense, and the library is right to throw the error. Use either `+44` or `(044)`

Comment: `phoneNum = "+" + Integer.valueOf(phoneNum.substring(0, phoneNum.indexOf(" "))
                .replaceAll("\\D", "")) + " " + phoneNum.substring(phoneNum.indexOf(" ") + 1);`

Answer (score 1):

The prefix `00` is not in all countries the 'official' prefix for the country code. And therefore the library does not by default accepts it.

You can test the library on that web page: http://libphonenumber.appspot.com/

You will see that your number is only accepted, when you select a default country that uses `00` as country code prefix. You can test it by setting `gb`  in the Default Country field.

The documentation of the library you can find on [that web page](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.googlecode.libphonenumber/libphonenumber/latest/com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/PhoneNumberUtil.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.String))

As you can see the second argument of the `parse` method is the defaultRegion. You must set a country that uses the phone number format that you want to parse.

This answers the second part of your question. As you will see the first part of your question has the same solution.