# how to get valid phone number length and validate it in app for particular country

Tags: android, validation, phone-number

I am allowing user to register with mobile number only and i wanna validate number in app without using internet, what i wanna do is that get valid phone number length of country selected by user , validate it with length  and formatting of number in that country's format.

for e.g. length of India's phone number is 10 and format is 0**********

Please tell me how to do that.

Comment: What language of code are you using? Are you just looking to enforce a character limit / minimum in a text field?

Comment: @Spyder_Says_hi  I am writing code for android app so it supports java. with length of phone that country's number i wanna validate weather user has entered correct number or not

Answer (score 7):

Add Following Code.

> In gradle

```
 compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.5.2'
```

> In Activity class

```
PhoneNumberUtil phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
    String isoCode = phoneNumberUtil.getRegionCodeForCountryCode(Integer.parseInt(countryCode));
    String  exampleNumber= String.valueOf(phoneNumberUtil.getExampleNumber(isoCode).getNationalNumber());
    int phoneLength=exampleNumber.length();
    editTextLoginPhone.setFilters( new InputFilter[] {
            new InputFilter.LengthFilter(phoneLength)});
```

Hope this code will help you.

Comment: @dennisrufigill prefixes code for respective country phone numbers(like 1 for US, 91 for India, 44 for UK) refer https://countrycode.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code for Indian Phone numbers:-

```
private static boolean isValidPhoneNumber(String mobile) {
    String regEx = "^[0-9]{10}$";
    return mobile.matches(regEx);
}
```

Comment: There are some countries who's phone number length is less than 10 or greater than 10 that's why i need length of valid phone number for the country selected by user

Answer (score 1):

if you not want to use the internet of checking the number valid or not , you can do programmatically though its long but solution can be this only .
Go to link  : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mobile_phone_number_series_by_country

and do programmatically the validation with conditions.

Comment: It will be very lengthy process. Isn't there any library to do in android

Answer (score 0):

you should force user to enter the country code and you can validate the phone number also just go through the links below

> https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber
>   and
>   [List of phone number country codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530377/list-of-phone-number-country-codes)