# Get telephone code from a country or country code - Twilio

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api

Using twilio, is there a way to get the telephone code for a given country or country code?

Eg: Given country as United States, it should return `1` as the telephone code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not believe Twilio supports that directly, but you might [find help in this solution set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530377/list-of-phone-number-country-codes).

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As WEBjuju pointed out, that answer has some good options. Notably, this is a [JSON file of countries and codes](http://country.io/phone.json) and if you need to go from country name to two letter code, then [this JSON will help](http://country.io/names.json).

If you are looking to extract this information from phone numbers, then [Google's libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) is the canonical resource and there is a [PHP version of libphonenumber available](https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php).

You could also use [Twilio's Lookup API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/lookups) to get information out of a phone number. With the Twilio PHP library, this would look like:

```
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
$sid = "YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID";
$token = "YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN";

$client = new Client($sid, $token);

$number = $client->lookups->phoneNumbers("+15108675309")->fetch();

echo $number->countryCode; // result - CA, US, etc.
```

Let me know if this helps at all.