# Convert CountryCode of Win32_OperatingSystem to the country string

Tags: powershell, wmi

We're trying to convert the `CountryCode` in to a human readable `String`.

**Code:**

```
$OS = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem

$OS | Select-Object CountryCode, OSLanguage, 
    @{N = 'OSDefaultLanguage'; E = {New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo([Int]$_.OSLanguage)}},
    @{N = 'OSCountryCode'; E = {New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo([Int]$_.CountryCode)}}
```

In the example above the property `OSCountryCode` is what we need. But it returns the value `ar` which is `Argentina` but it should return `United States` according to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for value `1`.

How can value `1` be correctly converted to `US` or something similar?

Comment: `CountryCode` is the _country calling code_ (the phone number routing prefix) for the associated country. You'll need to query an external API to convert the calling code to a country name

Comment: Or just don't use WMI and retrieve `[Globalization.RegionInfo]::CurrentRegion.TwoLetterISORegionName` (you can do this with PowerShell remoting for other machines).

Comment: When I run the code suggested by @JeroenMostert with `Invoke-Command` on another machine it always returns my own country and not that of the remote machine (Ex. 1 = US, 32 = BE). Is there a way to convert the value from the class `Win32_OperatingSystem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$OS = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem

$Culture = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultures("SpecificCultures") | Where {$_.LCID -eq $OS.OSLanguage}
$RegionInfo = New-Object System.Globalization.RegionInfo $Culture.Name

$OS | Select-Object CountryCode, OSLanguage, 
    @{N = 'OSDefaultLanguage'; E = {New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo([Int]$_.OSLanguage)}},
    @{N = 'OSCountryCode'; E = {$RegionInfo.TwoLetterISORegionName}},
    @{N = 'OSCountryName'; E = {$RegionInfo.DisplayName}}
```

Comment: Thx @iRon but that's not really what was asked. We're looking to match the `CountryCode` an `[int]` with the `CountryName` a `[String]`

Comment: @DarkLite1, sorry, I missed that, I have change my answer accordingly (and also added the country name.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @iRon but it's not converting the `$OS.CountryCode` to the two letter country name. The `$OS.CountryCode` is different from the `$OS.OSLanguage`. A given system can have OS language x and country Y.

Comment: This means that you will get multiple results if you want to convert a language to a country (e.g.dutch is spoken in both the Netherlands and Belgium) and also visa versa (e Belgium they speak French and

Comment: I think you're also getting a bit confused, just like I was. The `CountryCode` is 1 and the `OSLangauge` is 1033. The `CountryCode` 1 needs to be converted to `US` by only using the `CountryCode` and not the `OSLanguage` because it's not related. You can have a machine in `Germany` with language `Polish` without a problem....

Comment: I do not have the resource to confirm this, but I think you will need to run `Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem` under the SYSTEM account to get the system's OSLanguage/LCID ([Locale ID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms912047(v=winembedded.10).aspx)). If that doesn't work out for you, then you probably have to build a hard coded reference or get your reference from external, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25677570/1701026