# How to get country code (e.g. +61) in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, country-codes

I want to retrieve all country codes (like +61 for Australia) by giving country name. Is there built in method for retrieving country code in c# like

```
int countryCode = CultureInfo.getCountryCode("CountryName");
```

I saw some methods on internet but non of them is simple. I want simple method for retrieving country code by giving country name. I saw **Google libphonenumber** but is there any simple solution because I am having trouble while including thi library because I am using visual studio 2015 but this library is build in visual studio 2017. If this library is only the solution then how can I include this library in my visual studio 2015 project?

This is the code for getting all countries

```
public static List<string> countryList()
    {
        List<string> cultureList = new List<string>();
        CultureInfo[] info = getCultureInfo();

        foreach (CultureInfo culture in info)
        {
            RegionInfo region = new RegionInfo(culture.LCID);

            if (!(cultureList.Contains(region.EnglishName)))
            {
                cultureList.Add(region.EnglishName);
            }
        }

        cultureList.Sort();
        return cultureList;
    }
```

Now, how can I get country codes all of theses?

Comment: Do you need fuzzy matching of country name? Or does your input consist of full come ntry names perfectly matching he names .net uses?

Comment: I want a method which accept country name and give the appropriate country code. I am getting country names from .net built in Class "CultureInfo"

Comment: Why are you doing this in the first place? Sounds like a xy problem candidate to me.

Comment: then what is the best solution @CodeInChaos

Comment: Where do you get the country names from? Probably not a free text field, right?

Comment: @CodesInChaos see updated question

Comment: A quick Google search for "country code phone api" returns [CountryCodes.json](https://gist.github.com/Goles/3196253) Gist with lots of lists of these codes. Whether you need them to be always up to date is another detail that you did not provide and I would suggest using an API solution instead of copy-paste if you do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of phone number country codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530377/list-of-phone-number-country-codes)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, if you are talking about telephone prefix as country code, then there is no builtin way as I am aware of. Neither, culture nor region contains that information.

The easiest way is to take advantage of some free API, for example [geognos](http://www.geognos.com), where you can get the json data of a country using the code you can get from culture/region. For example data for Australia would be found using the [AU-code](http://www.geognos.com/api/en/countries/info/AU.json).

**Edit.**

To clarify my answer a bit, country code has nothing to do with tel. prefix and country codes at different formats can be fetched from culture/region information.