# How to get country code from mobile number in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am developing asp.net application where I need to find country from mobile number entered by user.

How can I achieve this in asp.net. is there any API available?

Please help me.

Comment: You cant find country code from the mobile number. A number valid in a country might be valid in other countries also.

Comment: you need to use location to identify country and then country code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530377/list-of-phone-number-country-codes ?